# find the **longitude and latitude** Using Jscript for Mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, mobile-phones, mobile-website

I have a scenatio where i have to find the **longitude and latitude** Using Jscript.

I have a mobile application where i have to implement this.
Or may be there is some way to use GPS to find the device current location

Please, Help

Thanks,
Regards,
Shivam Khare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at my small sample at http://nolovelust.com/post/mobile-geolocation-with-jquery-and-google-maps-api-and-aspnet-c.aspx I think it is what you need

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the Geolocation API: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so experienced with Android applications. But what you can always do is call Java functions from JavaScript. Hence, you could write a small applet which provides a (static) function to retrieve longitude and latitude. You would need to embed the applet in your page. Then you could call the function in your applet from Java Script.

Regards,

Martin.

Comment: Thanks for ur respond.. Basically i m using .net and i want to get the Lat Long from client side bcoz if if call the Server function it will return the location of the server(where site host) not the client(where site open)....

Comment: Since your client runs on Android, it's probably the easiest to use Java. I don't think you'll be able to access the GPS compoment with JScript. But it always also depends on the browser used on the device. Check-out the documentation of your target browsers.